# double tap to remove hover effect on mobile

Tags: css, hover, responsive

I have the following code that shows a text over an image when you hover on it:

```
<div class="single-service-item">
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img src="http://www.titantalk.com/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=319906&stc=1&d=1413391273" alt="Awesome Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="content">
          <p class="thm-btn yellow-bg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectet ur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna ali qua. Ut enim ad minim.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

With the following css

```
.single-service-item {
  padding-bottom: 42px;  
}
.single-service-item .img-holder {
  display: block;
  position: relative;  
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.single-service-item .img-holder img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  width: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  background-color: transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0s;
}
.overlay .box {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: border-color 0.4s ease 0s;
  width: 100%;  
}
.overlay .box .content {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;  
}
.overlay .box .content p {
  padding: 9.5px 24px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -75px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, -75px, 0px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s !important;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s !important;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.single-service-item:hover .img-holder .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(1, 48, 94, 0.85);
}
.single-service-item:hover .img-holder .overlay .box {
  border-color: #fdc716;
}
.single-service-item:hover .img-holder .overlay .box .content p {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
.services .single-service-item:hover .img-holder img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle of it:

https://jsfiddle.net/wkof6bod/

On mobile it works by taping on the image, but to remove the hover effect (the text) I have to tap outside of the image.

How do I make it so taping another time inside of the image removes the hover effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by toggling fake class

try to run code snippet

hope this is what you want!

```js
$(document).on('click', '.single-service-item', function() { 
$(this).removeClass('single-service-item').addClass('single-service-item-nothover');
});

$(document).on('click', '.single-service-item-nothover', function() { 
    $(this).removeClass('single-service-item-nothover').addClass('single-service-item');
});
```

```css
.single-service-item, .single-service-item-nothover {
  padding-bottom: 42px;  
}
.single-service-item .img-holder, 
.single-service-item-nothover .img-holder{
  display: block;
  position: relative;  
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.single-service-item .img-holder img , 
.single-service-item-nothover .img-holder img{
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  width: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  background-color: transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0s;
}
.overlay .box {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: border-color 0.4s ease 0s;
  width: 100%;  
}
.overlay .box .content {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;  
}
.overlay .box .content p {
  padding: 9.5px 24px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -75px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, -75px, 0px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s !important;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s !important;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.single-service-item:hover .img-holder .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(1, 48, 94, 0.85);
}
.single-service-item:hover .img-holder .overlay .box {
  border-color: #fdc716;
}
.single-service-item:hover .img-holder .overlay .box .content p {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
.services .single-service-item:hover .img-holder img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="single-service-item">
  <div class="img-holder">
    <img src="https://nidalmer.github.io/s2g/assets/images/solution-single/solution-v1-2.jpg" alt="Awesome Image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="content">
          <p class="thm-btn yellow-bg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectet ur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna ali qua. Ut enim ad minim.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```